# Understand netstat -i flgs

Tags: networking, netstat

Can anyone explain for me what each option in `Flg` means?

```
[root@apple ~]# netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface       MTU Met    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0       1500   0   110512      0      0      0     6660      0      0      0 BMRU
eth1       1500   0   110713      0      0      0     4533      0      0      0 BMRU
eth2       1500   0      733      0      0      0       17      0      0      0 BMRU
lo        16436   0       45      0      0      0       45      0      0      0 LRU
```

And are there any more?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're covered here in the guide: [Linux Network Administrators Guide
Chapter 5. Configuring TCP/IP Networking](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-iface.netstat.html).

*excerpt*

> The last column shows the flags that have been set for this interface. These characters are one-character versions of the long flag names that are printed when you display the interface configuration with ifconfig:

- **B** = A broadcast address has been set.
- **L** = This interface is a loopback device.
- **M** = [Supports multicast](https://github.com/ecki/net-tools/blob/master/lib/interface.c#L621)
- **O** = ARP is turned off for this interface.
- **P** = This is a point-to-point connection.
- **R** = Interface is running.
- **U** =  Interface is up.

Comment: I have my questions about this. Doing ip link set eth0 promisc on/off seems to toggle the P flag, not the M flag.

Comment: What's the different between "running" and "up"? Dose "up" means layer 2 is active, and "running" represent layer 3 is active?

Comment: @fajinyu, you ask a good question, but I don't think OSI layers are involved.  My current experience is, UP is controlled by `ifconfig UP` and is my means of advertising the interface as available to processes running on the server.  In my case, an interface connected by crossover cable does not become RUNNING until I power on the remote device.  I will attempt to update here as I learn more.